# Looking for a smart way to add new landing pages that are 90% similar. (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net

In an Asp.net website, I keep adding new landing pages by creating a new page that derives from a common master page. These "new" pages are 90% he same (only background image differs).

I ended up in my solution with 10+ similar .aspx pages. Is there a way to do this smarter. (not having to add a  different .aspx for every "new" page)?

Answer (score 2):

How about adding some code that renders the CSS `body {background-image:url(...)}` part?
This could do the trick without even having to have a code-behind DLL file:

```
<% string[] backgrounds = {"b1.jpg", "b2.jpg", "b3.jpg"};
   Random rnd = new Random();
   string background = backgrounds[rnd.next(0, backgrounds.length)];
%>
<style type="text/css">
  body {background-image:url("<%=background%>");}
</style>
```